# Send post request to Angular page from C# app

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, http, post

I know how to send a post request with angular to an API, but was wondering how to retrieve post request sent from an application.

Let say I have this C# post request:

```
    public string sendPost(string data)
    {
        // Create a request using a URL that can receive a post. 
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:5000/app/edit");
        // Set the Method property of the request to POST.
        request.Method = "POST";
        // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.

        string postData = "{\"data\":\"" + data + "\"}";

        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        // Get the request stream.
        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        // Write the data to the request stream.
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        // Close the Stream object.
        dataStream.Close();
        // Get the response.
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        // Display the status.
        Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
        // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        // Read the content.
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        // Display the content.
        Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
        // Clean up the streams.
        reader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        response.Close();

        return responseFromServer;
    }
```

In my angular app I have this controller:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('anbud')
      .controller('editController', ['$scope', 'localStorage', 'md5', '$routeParams', 'httpError',
          function ($scope, localStorage, md5, $routeParams, httpError) {

              function processHeaderData() {
                  console.log($routeParams.json);
              }

              processHeaderData();

          }]);

}());
```

I can send data via a the url and use routeParams, but I would like to use POST instead. How do I access the POST data?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing up front end and web server technologies.

Angular is a front end technology, what you mean sending a post to angular, actually means sending a request to the web server that hosts the angular website.

Once you make this clear, you just need to send an API call to the web server like how you do with angular, and the server will return the json data you need.

If you want to get the HTML representation of particular route, I'm afraid there is no good way to achieve this. This is not particular with angular either, any site that loads data with ajax call would have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Angular $http.post can also retrieve data. For security purposes, this is quite beneficial. Logic for that remains the same.

You could send data from your c# controller through this:

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace Sample.API.Controllers
{
    public class ContentDataController
    {

        [Route("api/ContentData")]
        [HttpPost]

        public HttpResponseMessage SamplePost(SampleRequest request)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response;
            try
            {
                var cda = dataContentAdapter(); 
                //Business logic here
                var result = cda.GetContent(request);

                //pass the above result to angular
                response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);
                response.Content.Headers.Expires = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(300));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ApplicationLogger.LogCompleteException(ex, "ContentDataController", "Post");
                HttpError myCustomError = new HttpError(ex.Message) { { "IsSuccess", false } };
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, myCustomError);
            }
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

With this, send a request from angular with whatever data that needs to be used in request. Favorable is to send json, parse the json in your business logic.

Create a `HttpResponseMessage` with the new payload for angular $http to recieve.